# How to populate nested ref in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with mongoose On a MongoDB database.
I have a Category model with subcategories (Subdocuments) nested inside it

```
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    children: [
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
```

And a Product Model with a categories field which references the Category model

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
   
    categories: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" }],
   
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

categories array contains multiple _id fields belonging to both top-level Categories and Categories -> Children

but when I try to populate the products.categories:

```
 Product.find()
      .populate('categories')
```

I only get the top level Categories not the nested children categories.

How can I populate nested levels too?

I tried:

```
Product.find()
      .populate({
        path: "categories",
        model: "Category",
        populate: {
          path: "children",
          model: "Category",
        },
      })
```

and it did not work. results were the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Category.children` is an array of objects with one `title` property. These are not [referenced documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs). Internally you are asking mongoose to perform a lookup on the `categories` collection. It expects to find an `ObjectId` in the `Category.children` array to use against the `_id` field in the `categories` collection to match against.

If you want to keep your `populate()` query as it is, which is written correctly, then you will need to modify your schema to store the `ObjectId` in the `children` array. Like this:

```js
    children: [{ 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: "Category" 
   }],
```

At the moment, your schema is set up to store the `Category.children` as an array of [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) as opposed to referenced documents.

Comment: is there another way so that I don't have to change the model schema?

Comment: Do you already have a lot of sub-documents stored or are you still designing? Aggregate allows you to do `$lookup` manually.

Comment: I have a seeded database already. Can you please help me with an example of $lookup? considering that I'm using mongoose as the ODM

Comment: Can you please provide a sample document of Product and Category from the products and categories collection?